# Unable to fild kazam package to remove it

Tags: fedora, package-management, rpm, dnf

Today I faced serious bug while using kazam (screen recorder) on fedora 38 workstation. The bug was unavailability to stop recording.

I tried to reinstall it by running in terminal `sudo dnf reinstall kazam`, but dnf answered me the following:

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:08:16 ago on Tue 29 Aug 2023 06:29:53 PM EET.
Package kazam available, but not installed.
No match for argument: kazam
Error: No packages marked for reinstall.
```

so, dnf could't find corresponding package

after that I tried delete the package trough built-in fedora software manager, but also couldn't find package 'kazam'

then, I tried to run `sudo rpm -qa | grep kazam` to fild the target package, nothing returned

`sudo yum list installed | grep kazam` finished with the same result - nothing

snap and flatpak also do not list kazam.

But kazam is starting! Where could i loose it? and how to delete kazam, if i cannot find it anywhere?

Comment: so, you didn't install it via dnf, rpm, flatpak nor snap. So, you must have installed it another way. This is your system, we can't guess what you manually did!

Comment: I am not so advanced linux user to install something manually. And this is the reason why I install everything using package managers. But anyway thank you for comment, from now I will be more accurate doing anything manually with system!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by installing kazam from one of third-party RPM repos.
After this action, package managers began to understand that kazam is installed.

More detailed process:

```
sudo dnf install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rpmsphere/noarch/master/r/rpmsphere-release-38-1.noarch.rpm
sudo dnf update && sudo dnf install kazam
sudo dnf remove kazam
sudo dnf autoremove
```

I faced the same issue on laptop also powered by fedora, but the same manipulations didn't work in this case

Comment: That just means you put a second installation there, which might, or might not, have contained exactly the same files as whatever you had installed